# How to import class in export function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to import class and use its public methods but its not working , what is correct way implement it.

main.ts

```
import {PromiseHandler } from './promiseHandler.ts';
    export function getUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
        const promiseHandler: new PromiseHandler();

    }
```

promiseHandler.ts

```
export class PromiseHandler {

    constructor() {};
    public executeAllPromises(promises) {

}
```

Comment: Are they in the same directory?

Comment: Just remove the `.ts`

Comment: no different directories but in code i just specified same

Comment: `const promiseHandler: new PromiseHandler();` should be `const promiseHandler: PromiseHandler = new PromiseHandler();`

Comment: You know what would be great? Actually specifying **what** got it to work; instead of just saying _Thanks it worked_.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn answer explain itself its not logical code that i have to explain how i have made it work it was just the syntax that was missing

Answer (score 0):

As told in comments, the correct syntax is

```
 const promiseHandler = new PromiseHandler();
```

(note the use of `=`, to assign the object created, while `:` would be to type the variable. The type is actually just PromiseHandler, so you could use both and write :

```
const promiseHandler: PromiseHandler = new PromiseHandler();
```

but I think that is not necessary to declare type here, TypeScript would detect it the correct type by itself with the initialisation with `= new...`